# Multithreading library that can share pointer data safely?

Tags: c++, c, windows, multithreading

Basically what I want to achieve is to share a dynamically allocated array of state flags among different threads to control the interactions between threads.

Are there any library that can achieve this flawlessly in Windows OS?

I tried Open MP, and it gives me all kinds of weird bugs and lots headache, even with omp flush all sometimes the data are still not up-to-date, volatile pointers didnt help either when the freqency of accesses are high,so the program become very unstable and inconsistent.

Are there any libraries that can handle shared and freqently updated and accessed data array (dynamic) better? Can TBB handle this situation?

Comment: The C++ standard library. You can pass shared data to thread objects on construction.

Comment: Sharing data between threads of a process?! You don't need any external library. Pass the data like object, variables, pointers,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common solution is to use mutexes. The basic idea is to wrap any access to a shared variable with a critical section, ie. a mutex lock:

```
 WaitForSingleObject(mutexHandle);
 // shared data access & modification
ReleaseMutex(mutexHandle);
```

- [CreateMutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

If you have access to C++11, try using `std::atomic<T>`  types, which let you share primitive types with atomic access semantics.

- [std::atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)

Answer (score 2):

Threads of the same process share the same heap, so memory allocated on this heap can be shared between those threads.

All the program needs to asure is protecting such "shared" memory against concurrent access.

The latter can be achieved by using locks, like mutexes.

Comment: I think the problem is compiler tries to load some of these shared data into registers, and for some weird reason, even with volatile sometimes it still cannot ensure the conherence of data among threads.

Comment: @user2188453: `volatile` won't help here (read here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming for more). Protect the concurrent access by a lock.

Comment: I tried omp critical and omp atomic, aint them estentially locks?

Comment: @user2188453: When using the win32 API and Windows thread the function around `EnterCriticalSection()` and `LeaveCritialSection()` might help. More about synchronisation functions for the win32 API can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your link, I will try using win32 API, btw I think volatile is still needed since otherwise the compiler can simply load some of the shared data into registers or doing other code "optimization", then even cache coherence cannot help the situtation.

Comment: @user2188453: If proper locking is used, `volatile` is not necessary as the compiler takes care of everything. Even more `volatile` could be considered a performance killer. Some more on this `volatile` discussion: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/volatile-considered-harmful.txt